# .css generation from .cls file not from the .cfg file

Tags: tex4ht, css, control, cfg

Is this possible to generate the .css file based on the customized .cls file not from config file (i.e. \Css {}).
 e.g., environment quote was defined in my class file as:

```
\newenvironment{quote}%
               {\list{}{\topsep9\p@\leftmargin\z@\rightmargin\z@}%
                \small\fontseries{b}\selectfont%
                \item\relax\}%
               {\endlist}%
```

and I am using the command `htlatex test "xhtml,fn-in" "-cunihft" "-cvalidate -p"` for HTML conversion and the converted HTML output came is:

```
                    <p class="indent" >
                    <span 
class="ptmr8t-x-x-90">Collusion  is  when  firms  use  history-dependent  strategies  to  sustain</span></p>
```

and CSS output is:

```
.quote {margin-bottom:0.25em; margin-top:0.25em; margin-left:1em; margin-right:1em; text-align:justify;}
```

means the css output actually not generated from the class (.cls) file instead it is from config file (.cfg which is used for tex4ht)

Now the expected output in CSS (for "quote") is:

```
.quote {font-size:80%; font-weight: bold;}
```

How can I achieve this? Please suggest...

Answer (score 2):

You can create `.4ht` file for your class. Say, if you have class `myclass.cls`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2017/07/11 Example LaTeX class]
\LoadClass[]{article}
\renewenvironment{quote}%
               {\list{}{\topsep9\p@\leftmargin\z@\rightmargin\z@}%
                \small\fontseries{b}\selectfont%
                \item\relax}%
               {\endlist}% 

\endinput
```

the configuring `.4ht` file will be `myclass.4ht`:

```
\ConfigureEnv{quote}{\NoFonts}{\EndNoFonts}{}{}
\Css{.quote{font-size:80\%; font-weight: bold;}}

\endinput
```

The configuration for `quote` environment only disables font heuristics inside the environment, to get rid of these `<span class="ptmr8t-x-x-90">` elements. The default configuration for `quote` in `tex4ht` will add `<div class="quote">` around the environment automatically, so you don't need to do that by hand. In the `\Css` command, you must escape the `%` character using `\%`.

The following sample file:

```
\documentclass{myclass}

\begin{document}
\section{Do common commands work?}

Yes, \textbf{they} \textit{do}\footnote{even footnotes?}.
\begin{quote}
  Collusion  is  when  firms  use  history-dependent  strategies  to  sustain
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

produces this result:

[image]

```xml
<div class="quote">
<!--l. 8--><p class="noindent" >Collusion is when firms use history-dependent strategies to sustain</p></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Michal for your response. Now the thing is converting the tex command to css commands. We do have test on the sample, whatever we specified in \Css {} will be generated in .css file. But we expect the properties needs to pickup from what we specified in our class file.

Comment: @MadyYuvi do you have some complete example? I think I've created some code which can get current font properties and save them to the CSS, but haven't tested it for two years: https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht/blob/master/textstyle4ht.sty

Comment: @MadyYuvi ah, here is a tutorial: http://michal-h21.github.io/samples/helpers4ht/textstyle.html

Comment: Shall I send the complete example (customized cls and TeX application file) to your mail?

Comment: @MadyYuvi yes you can. I am little bit busy recently, but I should be able to take a look at it in few days

Comment: Files sent to your gmail id, please confirm once you receive the same...

Comment: @MadyYuvi I've got them. I hope I could look at them later today.

Answer (score 0):

I saw Andrew's reply which is similar to the requirement what I asked, and the link is [Can we simplify the \Configure coding in CFG file in tex4ht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380624/can-we-simplify-the-configure-coding-in-cfg-file-in-tex4ht) Thanks for everyone who tried...