# Can we simplify the \Configure coding in CFG file in tex4ht

Tags: tex4ht, cfg

I m new to tex and using tex4ht conversion with a ".cfg" file. In that I need to configure more than 600 elements. Hence I need to add for all the 600 elements in cfg.

Example:

sample.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,czech]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epub}
\begin{document}
\HalfTitle{Machine Learners}
\Title{Title}
\end{document}
```

epub.sty

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{epub}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{framed}%
\usepackage{glossaries}%
\usepackage[tex4ht]{hyperref}%
\def\toprule{\hline}%
\def\botrule{\hline}%
\def\midrule{\hline}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{pgffor}% for the \foreach command
\newcommand{\HalfTitle}[1]{%
\Large#1%
}%

\newcommand{\Title}[1]{\Large#1}%

\endinput
```

epub.cfg

```
\Preamble{xhtml,fn-in,epub}
\RequirePackage{pgffor}% for the \foreach command

\renewcommand\ConfigurePar[1]{
  \foreach \para/\cls in {#1}{
    \Configure{\para}{\HCode{<p class="\cls">}}{\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}%
    }
}

\begin{document}
\ConfigurePar{
  HalfTitle/TPHT,
  booktitle/TPT,
}
\EndPreamble
```

epub.4ht

```
\newcommand\ConfigurePar[1]{
 \foreach \paa/\cls in {#1}{
    \NewConfigure{\paa}{2}
    \let\tmp:\paa\\paa
    \renewcommand\\paa[1]{\a:\paa\tmp:\paa#1\b:\paa} 
    \Configure{\paa}{\HCode{<p class="\cls">}}{\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}%
   }
}
```

and  I am using the following command for conversion

```
htlatex sample "epub,xhtml" " -cunihft" "-cvalidate -p"
```

Is that possible to minimize the config code by passing ("halftitle", "TPHT") and ("booktitle", "TPT") as arguments in any external file and in use the argument values in CFG file. Like:

```
\Configure{ARG1}{\IgnorePar \EndP\HCode{<p class="ARG2">}}{\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}%
```

Request your suggestions.

Thanks in advance
Christober

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

I would do this differently. Rather than using `\Configure` I would simply redefine the commands in the cfg file. Previously, I was using the `\foreach` command from [pgffor](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) but instead it seems better to use `\forcsvlist` from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package. Then you can do what (I think) you want using

```
\newcommand\ConfigurePar[1]{\realConfigurePar#1!}
\def\realConfigurePar#1/#2!{% extract #1 up to / and then #2 up to !
    \csdef{#1}##1{\HCode{<p class="#2">}##1\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}%
}

\forcsvlist\ConfigurePar{
  HalfTitle/TPHT,
  Title/TPT
}
```

So, `\forcsvlist` passes each element of the comma separated list to `\ConfigurePar`. In order to separate  out the command name and the class name, `\ConfigurePar` gives everything to `\realConfigurePar`, which then redefines the corresponding LaTeX command so that it produces the required html.

In full gory detail: using the cfg file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,fn-in,epub}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}% for the \forsvlist command

\newcommand\ConfigurePar[1]{\realConfigurePar#1!}
\def\realConfigurePar#1/#2!{%
    \csdef{#1}##1{\HCode{<p class="#2">}##1\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}%
}

\begin{document}
\forcsvlist\ConfigurePar{
  HalfTitle/TPHT,
  Title/TPT
}

\EndPreamble
```

together with the latex file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,czech]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\ProvidesPackage{epub}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{framed}%
\usepackage{glossaries}%
\usepackage[tex4ht]{hyperref}%
\def\toprule{\hline}%
\def\botrule{\hline}%
\def\midrule{\hline}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{pgffor}% for the \foreach command
\newcommand{\HalfTitle}[1]{%
\Large#1%
}%

\newcommand{\Title}[1]{\Large#1}%
\begin{document}
\HalfTitle{Machine Learners}
\Title{Title}
\end{document}
```

produces the html file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<!--http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd-->  
<html xml:lang="cs" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
> 
<head>
   <title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<!-- html,xhtml,fn-in,epub --> 
<meta name="src" content="s.tex" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="s.css" /> 
</head><body 
>
<!--l. 26--><p class="noindent" ><p class="TPHT">Machine Learners</p> 
 <p class="TPT ">Title</p> 
 </p> 
</body></html>
```

In particular, `Machine Learners` and `Title` are wrapped in paragraph tags with the expected classes. Also, I don't think that the 4ht file is necessary.

Btw, rather than using htlatex directly I recommend using [make4ht](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/make4ht) package instead. To produce the html file above I used the command:

```
make4ht  -c epub.cfg sample.tex
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I used the code but still facing some issues. Can I attach the working sample files for your review with the updated config file through email?

Comment: HI Andrew, I have updated code but here issue is we are defining a command with some action like loop through the input (correct me if i am wrong). However we need to execute the command with argument like \ConfigurePar{
  HalfTitle/TPHT,
}
before our \begin{document} then only it take and working. But not producing the expected result. Instead, producing blank tags like <p class="TPHT"></p>. Can you suggest me am i correct?

Comment: Can you please edit your original post and provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) so that I can properly test the code? You should provide a minimal latex file that compiles with (pdf)latex, together with a cfg file with your `\Configure` statements that can be run through tex4ht/make4ht. This makes it easier for people to test code against what you want.

Comment: I have modified the question and added MWE for your review...

Comment: @Andrew you are amazing, your answer fully fit for my requirement also...

Comment: @christoberC, MadyYuvi Glad it was useful!!